# Django client install postgresql/postgis on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango, ubuntu

Does anyone know what apt packages one should install for a postgres(8.4)/postgis(1.5) django (1.4) **client** on ubuntu 12.04?

All recipes seem to assume that I want to install the full postgres/postgis database server on the machine, but I have a external database server so I only want the packages that can connect to that.

For a full server I use:

```
apt-get install binutils gdal-bin libproj-dev postgresql-8.4-postgis postgresql-server-dev-8.4 python-psycopg2 python-setuptools
```

Comment: For django, dont forget virtualenv :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it but try changing your apt-get to

`apt-get install binutils gdal-bin libproj-dev postgresql-9.1-postgis postgresql-server-dev-9.1 python-psycopg2 python-setuptools`

should do the trick. As its just the client its backwards compatible with older versions of postgresql.

`postgresql-8.4-postgis` is only available on lucid (10.04) the future releases (11.04) onwards use `postgresql-9.1-postgis`

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=postgresql+postgis

EDIT:

`apt-get install binutils gdal-bin libproj-dev postgis python-psycopg2 python-setuptools` does the trick

Comment: Tried it, but `postgresql-9.1-postgis` also has `postgresql-9.1` as an dependency. Is it possible to do this without that?

Comment: Thinking about it can't you just use `python3-postgresql` you shouldn't need any of the postgis stuff apart from on the server.

Comment: Had a look if you just want the userland binaries, common files and documentation for postgis then you need to install `postgis` not `postgresql-9.1-postgis`

Comment: Found it: `apt-get install binutils gdal-bin libproj-dev postgis python-psycopg2 python-setuptools`

Comment: Cool have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, but other comments where useful too...